# Debian 9.8 Cinammon Edit Default Terminal with Arguments

Tags: debian, gnome-terminal

I am trying to modify Cinnamon 3.2.7 right-click menu "Open in terminal" option. I successfully got it to launch `gnome-terminal` using `dconf-editor` by editing the `org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal.exec` schema. This works, but I want to launch the terminal with an argument as such:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=132x24
```

When I set

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal.exec-arg
```

to

```
--geometry=132x24
```

it has no effect on the program. I can launch `gnome-terminal` with this argument in shortcuts and it works just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The route is not `exec-args` but `exec`. Try with this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that, and now the terminal doesn't not launch anymore. I used the exact same schema and custom value as you.  I tried putting a different terminal such as ```mate-terminal``` just to validate it has an effect and it does launch another terminal I just can't add arguments in that way.

Comment: @David Uh, in my cinnamon (Linux Mint) works flawlessly. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Debian 9.8. What Cinnamon version are u using? Maybe its a bug with my version of Cinnamon.

Comment: `Cinnamon 4.0.10`

Comment: Hmm i am using Cinnamon 3.2.7-4. Let me try to find an updated version of it and see if it'll work. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I would have to download the upgraded Cinnamon from the sid source, which i would not like to do. I guess it is a bug with this version of Cinnamon and I will wait until the update it on Debian. Thanks